# How can I "require" code from another .rb file like in PHP?

Tags: ruby, include, eval, require, proc

Coming to Ruby from a PHP background, I'm used to being able to use `require`, `require_once`, `include`, or `include_once` which all have a similar effect, but the key being they continue to process code *in the same scope* where the `include` / `require` command was invoked.

#### Example:

> sub.php

```
<?php
echo $foo;
```

> main.php

```
<?php
$foo = 1234;
include('sub.php'); // outputs '1234'
```

When I first started using Ruby I tried to include / require / require_relative / load other `.rb` files, and after becoming a little frustrated with not having it work how I would expect it to I decided that there were better ways to go about breaking up large files and that Ruby didn't need to behave in the same way PHP did.

However, occasionally I feel that for testing purposes it would be nice to to load code from another `.rb` file in the way PHP does - in the same scope with access to all the same variables - without having to use class / instance variables or constants. Is this possible? Maybe somehow using a proc / binding / or eval command?

Again, I'm not advocating that this should be used during development - but I am curious if it is possible -  and if so, how?

Comment: Do you want to import external ruby lib?

Comment: Not particularly, just want to be able to point to a file and have a few lines of code from it run in the current scope

Comment: @JuanjoSalvador: `load` doesn't do that - it only gives an option to prevent the *included* file from polluting the namespace of the *including* file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, although certainly not something I'd recommend doing. This works:

`includer.rb`:

```
puts var
```

`include.rb`:

```
var = "Hello!"

eval(File.read("include.rb"), binding)
```

Running this (Ruby 2.2.1, Ruby 1.9.3) will print `Hello!`. It works simply: `eval` takes an optional binding with which to evaluate the code it is passed, and `Kernel#binding` returns the current binding.

Answer (score 2):

To have code run in same binding, you could simply `eval` the file contents as follows:

**example.rb**

```
class Example
    def self.called_by_include
      "value for bar"
    end

    def foo
      puts "Called foo"
    end

    eval( File.read( 'included.rb' ) )
end

Example.new.bar
```

**included.rb**

```
BAR_CONSTANT = called_by_include
def bar
  puts BAR_CONSTANT
end
```

Running `ruby example.rb` produces output

> value for bar

The important thing is the `eval( File.read( 'included.rb' ) )` code, which if you really wanted you could define as a class method on `Object`, to allow arbitrary source to be included with a convenience function*. The use of constants, class variables etc just shows influences working in both directions between the two pieces of source code.

It would be bad practice to use this in any production code. Ruby gives you much better tools for meta-programming, such as ability to use mix-ins, re-open classes, define methods from blocks etc.

---

* Something like this

```
class Object
  def self.include_source filename
    eval( File.read( filename ) )
  end
end
```

And the line in `example.rb` would become just

```
include_source 'included.rb'
```

Again I have to repeat this is not such a great idea . . .

Answer (score -1):

To import external *.rb file* in your code, I'm not sure but I think it have to be a gem.

Use `require` followed by the name of the gem you want to import.

Example

```
require 'foobar'
# do some stuff
```

Or you can use `load` to import *entire rb file*

```
load 'foobar.rb'
# do some stuff
```

Good luck and sorry for my english

Comment: No, the external file does not have to be related to a gem.  It can be, but does not have to be.  The question is quite a bit more complicated than just importing code though, it is asking about scoping issues as well.